# Zoom - Magento - doesn't work

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

The images of my shop stopped working. I use magento 1.7.0.2. I can't zoom. How can I fix it? Already tried to 775 /js and subfolders. Then I replaced the default zoom with Easy Lightbox but it also didn't work.

image here http://imageshack.us/a/img834/9338/bjw.png

Comment: This is a programming forum.  This question may be a better fit over here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you. I do think your recommendation is a better place to solve my problem.